Wifi stopped to work after kernel upgrade
I upgraded Linux Mint's kernel and my wifi stopped to work. How can I get it back to work as my ethernet connection works well, and how do I start to debug the issue? hwinfo seems to be too big file to be attached. This is a laptop and Cinnamon desktop. I can't see available wifi networks.
 iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

(base) jaakko@jaakko-Lenovo-ideapad-L340-17IWL:~$ lspci | grep -E -i --color 'network|ethernet|wireless|wi-fi'
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
(base) jaakko@jaakko-Lenovo-ideapad-L340-17IWL:~$ 


Start by editing your question and adding some information so we can help you. What is your hardware? Is this a laptop? Desktop? What it your network card? How is wifi not working? Is the card not being seen (output of iwconfig?), is it being seen but it sees no networks? Can it see networks but not connect? The more detail you give us, the better the chances someone can help.

Probably the kernel upgrade isn't correctly done, you need to install the kernel headers to make the Wi-Fi module correctly built.
Install the kernel headers:
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Reinstall the rtl8821ce-dkms
sudo apt reinstall rtl8821ce-dkms

You can make the Wi-Fi card work to get an Internet connection by booting the previous kernel, then install the missing packages.

...and when you reinstall, don't do it blindly!  Actually check and see if it got errors....like failed to update initrd because your disk is full...

@user10489 Right,  You need to monitor the installation process, DKMS may fail to build the wifi kernel module for some reasons.

@GAD3R Thanks! I manage to downgrade my kernel but I still can't see wifi networks available.

If downgrading kernel didn't work, almost certainly the driver was updated and dkms build failed for all kernels, probably for the same reason.  Maybe also check /var/crash/
